# Largest order statistics of non-identical distributions when extra information is available

Tags: random-variable, order-statistics

Suppose we have two independent draws, one from a distribution $F_1$ and the other from a distribution $F_2$. The two distributions have the same support, say $[0, 1]$.

The distribution of the largest order statistic is then $F_1 F_2$.

My question is if we happen to know the larger value is drawn from the first distribution $F_1$, what should the distribution of the larger value be? Is it still be $F_1F_2$ or something else?

Comment: If the distributions are different then I would expect "something else" and more complicated

Comment: If the distributions are the same then its CDF would still be $F_1F_2$